# Number of seeks() when reading a file in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I want to make sure I am getting this concept right:

In Hadoop the Definite Guide it is stated that: "the goal while designing a file system is always to reduce the number of seeks in comparison to the amount of data to be transferred." In this statement the author is referring to the "seeks()" of Hadoop logical blocks, right?

I am thinking that no matter how big the Hadoop block size is (64MB or 128MB or bigger) the number of seeks of the physical blocks (which are usually 4KB or 8KB) that the underlying filesystem (e.g. ext3/fat) will have to perform will be the same no matter the size of Hadoop block size.

Example: To keep numbers simple, assume underlying file system block size is 1MB. We want to read a file of size 128MB. If the Hadoop block size is 64MB, the file occupies 2 blocks. When reading there are 128 seeks. if the Hadoop block size is increased to 128MB, the number of seeks performed by the files system is still 128. In the second case, Hadoop will perform 1 seek instead of 2.

Is my understanding correct?

If I am correct, a substantial performance improvement by increasing block size will only be observed only for very large files, right? I am thinking that in the case of files that are in the 1~GB size range, reducing the number of seeks from ~20 seeks (64MB block size) to ~10 seek (128MB block size) shouldn't make much of a difference, right?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that increasing the file system block size will improve performance. Linux requires that the block size be less than or equal to the page size. The x86 page size is limited to 4K; therefore, the largest block size that you can use is 4K even if the file system can support larger block sizes. The performance benefits of a large block size and page size are significant: reduction in read/write system calls, reduction in rotational delays and seeks (don't begin to consider SSDs), fewer context switches, improved cache locality, fewer TLB misses, etc. This is all goodness.

I analytically modeled the benefits of various block sizes based on our disk usage pattern and in some cases predicted order of magnitude improvements from the disk subsystem. This would shift the performance bottleneck elsewhere.

You are correct that substantial performance gains are possible. Unfortunately, a certain engineer who controls such improvements sees no value in page sizes larger than 4K. He mocks enterprise users who need high perform from largely homogeneous workloads on big iron and focuses on heterogeneous workloads that are interactively run on desktop or laptop systems where high performance is unimportant.